# Using session variable to show login/logout

Tags: html, session, authentication, logout

I'm trying to use session variables so that when the user logs in on a user account or an admin account it changes the navigation bar to say Log out instead of Log in. However it doesn't seem to change the navigation bar! Can anyone help me out?

Here's my loginsubmit.php

```
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include 'connection.php';
include 'loginform.php';
?>
<center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Users WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $queryadmin = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Admin WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
    $resultadmin = mysqli_query($connection, $queryadmin);
    $rowadmin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadmin);

    if ($row["cnt"] > 0) 
    {
        $_SESSION["userlogged"] =  $user;
        header("Location: homepage.php");
    } 
    else if ($rowadmin["cnt"] > 0 )
        {
            $_SESSION["userlogged"] = $user;
            header("Location: homepage.php");
        }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Not a valid login';
    }
}
?>
</center>
```

So it runs through the if statements and sets the session variables. Now going back to my housestyle.php, it runs through the if statements, if it's been set, it will show the navigation bar with logout, else, show login. But it doesn't seem to be working, it just displays the navigation bar with Login:

```
<body>

    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userlogged']))
    {   
    ?>
    <center>
    <nav>
    <ul class="horizontal_menu">

      <li>

        <a href="Homepage.php" title="Back to the home page">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Products.php" title="Check out the products in stock">PRODUCTS</a>

      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="aboutus.php" title="About the company">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="contactus.php" title="Contact information for the company">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>


      <li>
     <a href="loginform.php" title="Log into your existing account">LOG OUT</a>
     </li>
     </center>
    </nav>
    </ul>
    <ul class="search_bar">
    <form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm" placeholder="search..." required><input type="button" value="search" name="Search">
    </form>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
    <center>
    <nav>
    <ul class="horizontal_menu">

      <li>

        <a href="Homepage.php" title="Back to the home page">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Products.php" title="Check out the products in stock">PRODUCTS</a>

      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="aboutus.php" title="About the company">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="contactus.php" title="Contact information for the company">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>


      <li>
     <a href="loginform.php" title="Log into your existing account">LOG IN</a>
     </li>
     <li>
     <a href="registrationform.php" title="Register a new account">REGISTER</a>
     </li>
     </center>
    </nav>
    </ul>
    <ul class="search_bar">
    <form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm" placeholder="search..." required><input type="button" value="search" name="Search">
    </form>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting your session after an output.

```
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php
session_start();
```

Move `session_start();` before any output.

Like:

```
<?php
//No any other output before, like <html>, space, so nothing.
session_start();
?>
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">
```

**EDIT:**

Based on Lucas answer, you also need to add `session_start()` to your `housestyle.php`.

**NOTE**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

should be the first, to catch your error.

In your case, I could create a `startup.php`, what includes this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
```

and `include('startup.php');` in all of your php file.

Comment: Hi mate. I've done this, but when I log in it still doesn't change the navigation bar to say Log out! :(

Comment: adding session_start(); works when included on housestyle.php! THaknyou for your answer though mate

Answer (score 1):

you forgot session_start() on housestyle.php

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Adding  session_start() on housestyle.php solve the issue , at least in my opinion